# c# multiple classes same methods

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have 4 classes

```
class A {
    private List<InputSelector> _lstA = new List<InputSelector();
    private List<InputSelector> _lstB = new List<InputSelector();
    private List<InputSelector> _lstC = new List<InputSelector();

    public A(){
        _lstA.Add(new InputSelector{ description = "ItemA"});
        _lstB.Add(new InputSelector{ description = "ItemB"});
        _lstC.Add(new InputSelector{ description = "ItemC"});
    }

    public List<InputSelector> getInputSelector(InputSelectorEnum input) {
        switch(type){
             case(InputSelectorEnum.A):
                 return _lstA;
             case(InputSelectorEnum.B):
                 return _lstB;
             case(InputSelectorEnum.C):
                 return _lstC;
        }
    }
}
[...]
class D {
    private List<InputSelector> _lstA = new List<InputSelector();
    private List<InputSelector> _lstB = new List<InputSelector();
    private List<InputSelector> _lstC = new List<InputSelector();

    public D(){
        _lstA.Add(new InputSelector{ description = "ItemA"});
        _lstB.Add(new InputSelector{ description = "ItemB"});
        _lstC.Add(new InputSelector{ description = "ItemC"});
    }

    public List<InputSelector> getInputSelector(InputSelectorEnum input) {
        switch(type){
             case(InputSelectorEnum.A):
                 return _lstA;
             case(InputSelectorEnum.B):
                 return _lstB;
             case(InputSelectorEnum.C):
                 return _lstC;
        }
    }
}
```

This is obviously not the best DRY pattern but I can't get my head around a better pattern.

Do you have any suggestion on how to simplify this/make it easier to modify/extend and I don't have to repeat it for all 4 classes?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you point out how are the classes different? I can't see any difference here. If they are all the same, why not just use one class instead?

Comment: That is a very relevant question, and you are indeed correct. There's no difference between the classes. They are exactely the same. I feel a bit stupid now and have to blame working too much lately with too little sleep. Post it as an answer and I'll give you the credit for it, thanks!

Comment: Also ... your classes could implement a Dictionary<InputSelectorEnum,List<InputSelector>> to avoid the Switch.

Comment: Thank you! Good suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your classes are exactly the same. They can be merged into a single one.

You almost never need classes that are exactly the same. This is because classes are just blueprints for objects. Two blueprints are no more useful than one. Your intention here might be to create 4 objects that are the same, `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` which you want to mutate later on, but you accidentally created 4 classes instead.